# "No exact matches in call to initializer" using OpenKitten/BSON package

Tags: swift, bson, swift-package-manager

I am trying to use the [OpenKitten/BSON](https://github.com/OpenKitten/BSON) Swift package on a new project, and I'm unable to access any values on a created `Document` while following the README instructions.

The compiler is unable to use the value.

```swift
let data: Document = [ "type": "createSession" ]
let type = String(data["type"])
//         ^ No exact matches in call to initializer 
print(type);
```

If I add a breakpoint and observe the value using lldb, it does have a debugger output, so the data exists:

```
(lldb) vo data
(BSON.Document) data = ▿ ["type": "createSession"]
  ▿ storage : ByteBuffer (...)
```

I'm still learning Swift, and it seems this library implements a lot of advanced concepts that I'm still not sure how to properly unwrap.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Understanding the error: " No exact matches in call to initializer": It's not that `data` is nil/has no value (from your `po data`), it's just that there is no method `init(_ document: Document)` for String. So you can't do ` String(data["type"])`.

Comment: @Larme that would be the case if I was trying to `String(data)`, but I'm not sure what `data["type"]` would be, and how to access its value.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the REAMDE was outdated and with inaccurate information.

One way to properly decode a `Document` involves using `BSONDecoder().decode(type, from)`, such as this:

```swift
struct Message: Codable {
  let type: String;
}

let data: Document = [ "type": "createSession" ]

do {
  let message = try BSONDecoder().decode(Message.self, from: Document(data: data))
  print(message.type);
  // This should work
} catch {
  print("error is \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```